In Golang, HTTP Client RoundTripper wraps Payload with an unnecessary object
Issue
It seems that the HTTP Client is sending a different message than the Payload I want to send to the server.

In the sample code, you can see that the Payload passed to http.NewRequest is a simple hierarchical object.

{"message":"Hello, world!"}


However, the Payload confirmed in RoundTripper seems to be wrapped with one more unnecessary object, making it a deeper layer.

{{"message":"Hello, world!"}}



If anyone has encountered the same problem, please let me know how to resolve this.
Code
I wrote code like below.
The results are different between log numbers 1 and 2 in the output.
As a workaround, I am currently solving the problem by removing the outermost {}.
However, it's likely that I'm using RoundTripper incorrectly, so I'd like a different solution.
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Object struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type myRoundTripper struct {
    roundTripper http.RoundTripper
}

func (rt *myRoundTripper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    fmt.Printf("2. Payload in RoundTrip: %s\n", req.Body)
    return rt.roundTripper.RoundTrip(req)
}

func main() {

    object := Object{
        Message: "Hello, world!",
    }

    payload, err := json.Marshal(object)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("1. Original Payload: %s\n", string(payload))

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &myRoundTripper{
            roundTripper: http.DefaultTransport,
        },
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "http://localhost:8080/", bytes.NewBuffer(payload))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Response: %v\n", res)
}

Output
$ go run main.go
1. Original Payload: {"message":"Hello, world!"}
2. Payload in RoundTrip: {{"message":"Hello, world!"}}
Response: &{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Length:[240] Content-Type:[text/plain; charset=utf-8] Date:[Sun, 27 Oct 2024 16:24:31 GMT] Status:[200 OK]] 0xc000034140 240 [] false false map[] 0xc0000de360 <nil>}

Go version
$ go version
go version go1.22.5 darwin/amd64


You cannot read the response body just like that in the roundtripper. Just stop these crude attempts to debug your code.

Two more comments: Stop that go run main.go business and the name of the language is called Go.

The extra {} is a side effect of trying to format the io.ReadCloser, specifically io.nopCloserWriterTo, as a %s (string).
If you read from it, you'll get the expected result:
func (rt *myRoundTripper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    defer req.Body.Close()
    read, _ := io.ReadAll(req.Body)
    fmt.Printf("2. Payload in RoundTrip: %s\n", read)
    return rt.roundTripper.RoundTrip(req)
}

Note that:

In a production web server, the io.ReadCloser would have a different concrete type (that doesn't contain all the bytes already).
Reading from the req.Body will mean that an empty body is passed to rt.roundTripper.RoundTrip().
If you do use io.ReadAll in  real code, you should handle the potential error.

